# recursive setTimeout - not a variable

Tags: javascript, timer

I want to make a timer that counts down from some initial number and stops  when it gets to zero.

I originally did this with setInterval, but I wanted to separate the timer (setInterval) from the count down function, and was finding it difficult to terminate the setInterval.

I'm currently trying to achieve the same thing with a setTimeout which conditionally calls the same setTimeout again, but it doesn't work.

```js
function Timer(initialTime) {
  this.time = initialTime;
  this.tickTock = null
}

Timer.prototype.countDown = function() {
  if (this.time <= 0) {
    clearTimeout(this.tickTock);
  } else {
    console.log(this.time);
    this.time--;
    this.proceed();
  }
}

Timer.prototype.proceed = function() {
  this.tickTock = setTimeout(this.countDown, 3000);
}

var timer = new Timer(10);
timer.proceed();
```

When calling `timer.proceed()`, I'm getting error:

> TypeError: this.proceed is not a function
>
> at Timer.countDown [as _onTimeout]

How can I refer to the proceed function from within the countDown function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback to `setTimeout` is not bound to your object but it's bound to `window` thus `this` is the `window` objet not your `timer` object. You can bind the callback using [**Function.prototype.bind**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like this:

```
this.tickTock = setTimeout(this.countDown.bind(this), 3000);
```

**Note:** when using `setTimeout` there will be no need for `this.tickTock`, you can stop the counting down by not calling another `proceed`. You can keep it but it will be of no use. (see the code snippet bellow).

**Working code snippet:**

```js
function Timer(initialTime) {
  this.time = initialTime;
}

Timer.prototype.countDown = function() {
  if (this.time <= 0) { // if the counter is less or equal 0, return and don't call proceed
    return;
  }
  // otherwise continue
  console.log(this.time);
  this.time--;
  this.proceed();  
}

Timer.prototype.proceed = function() {
  setTimeout(this.countDown.bind(this), 1000);
}

var timer = new Timer(10);
timer.proceed();
```

Comment: It's not "bound" to *window* either. Since *this* isn't set in the call, it defaults to *window*. In strict mode, it would be undefined.

Comment: @RobG I think you're wrong! It's bound to `window` because `setTimeout` is a `window` function (`window["setTimeout"]`). Just log it and check!

Comment: Well, there you go! Using strict mode it seems that the function is called as *window.countDown* (or at least *window* is assigned to *this*), so I've learned something today, and it's  not even morning tea time yet! ;-)